# Dois subscribes na mesma função?

Tags: html, angular

Eu tenho uma função em `Typescript` na qual seu retorno está direcionado para um input no `formGroup`, porem n consigo usar o mesmo retorno em outro campo, só se tiver com o mesmo nome.

Eu preciso utilizar o retorno em tabela HTML e não consigo colocar um `formControlName` em uma `td`

## Requisição

```
case 'nomeProduto':
 params = params.set('cod', formGroup.controls['codigoProduto'].value);
 this.retornaNomeApi(NEGOCIUS_API + '/Pesquisa/RetornaNome', params)
     .subscribe(nome => formGroup.patchValue({
         nomeProduto: nome.result
      }));
break;
```

## Input que chama a função

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>Código:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <!--Input que chama a função do nome do produto-->
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product" formControlName="codigoProduto" (keydown.tab)="this.formpesquisaservice.retornaNome('nomeProduto', this.digitacaoForm)" style="background-color: white;">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <a class="btn btn-info" onclick="OpenConsulta('prod');" id="pedido">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

## Input que recebe a função

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label>Produto:</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="nomeProduto">
</div>
```

Comment: Porque não coloca o retorno do subscrible em uma variável? Não atenderia?

Comment: Explicar melhor o problema com mais detalhes eu tento te ajudar.

Comment: uma edição com o html e uma melhor explicação é necessária

Comment: Na realidade, se eu coloco em uma variável, o nome não é retornado nos inputs que eu preciso, por isso perguntei se existe alguma forma de colocar dois subscribes...

Comment: Eu editei colocando os html básicos, com o input que chama a função, e com o input que recebe, precisam de mais alguma informação? Se precisar é só avisar :D

Comment: cara eu creio que tem algo errado... vc não precisa retornar nada pro html... o angular é _two-way data binding_ você conseguiria adicionar o valor de retorno da requisição em uma variável ou modelo pra trabalhar com o form... o que talvez teria problema é se o form precisar ser dinâmico, mas ai poderia usar o form builder.... qual a versão do angular que está usando?

Comment: @picossi estou usando o angular 2, porem ainda não consegui a maneira de retorno, pra simplificar, quero q o mesmo valor que retorna dessa função, também retorne direto para um model, da maneira que consiga chamar seu valor através da forma simples "{{exemplo.exemplo}}"